# Session bean being reinstantiated in same session (in 2 Liferay portlets)

Tags: jsf, javabeans, liferay

I have 2 JSF portlets (one ICEfaces, one straight JSF) in a single Liferay project (single war) in LR 6.1 GA1. My session bean is annotated with @ManagedBean and @SessionScoped and my faces-config.xml contains

```
    <managed-bean>
    <managed-bean-name>wtfBean</managed-bean-name>
    <managed-bean-class>com.test.beans.WtfBean</managed-bean-class>
    <managed-bean-scope>session</managed-bean-scope>
</managed-bean>
```

I've placed each of the portlets on a separate web page. I print to System.out in my bean's constructor (and I've traced the whole process), and my bean is being instantiated *twice*.

Is there something else I should be doing to share my session data?

Thanks.

Comment: Why are you registering the bean the old JSF 1.x way in `faces-config.xml` if you're already using the new JSF 2.x annotations? Note that in a normal JSF environment (at least, on servlets), the `faces-config.xml` one would override any annotations. I don't do portlets, but perhaps it's doing it differently or behaving buggy. Try to remove one of the ways you're registering the bean.

Answer (score 1):

Your configuration is fine. It's caused by portlet bridge.

Comment: Are you saying I'm screwed, or is there something I can do?